# Can Magento talk directly to an ERP?

Tags: database, web-services

I don't know much about ERPs or Magento and wanted to find out if Magento Community version talk directly to an ERP, specifically [Infor M3](http://www.infor.com/product-summary/erp/m3/)

Using V1.9 of Magento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, out of the box Magento can't push data to any ERP system.

You need an *integration* for that.

That is either a magento module built for your ERP of choice (usually provided for free by the ERP vendor) OR your ERP system syncs data with magento by using the magento API (REST or SOAP) which magento comes with out-of-the-box. The magento API can be used by any 3rd party system to create/update products, categories, etc.

If your ERP can be configured to use magento API all you need to do is provide it the OAuth credentials you create in magento admin.

More info on what the the Magento (v2.2) API can do and how to use it:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/get-started/bk-get-started-api.html

Comment: Thank you! Is this the same for v1.9 too? Do you think if I contacted the ERP, they should be able to tell me?

Comment: Agreed. We had to write a integration/extension for Magento to talk to SAP.

Comment: @AmyLing Yes, it's the same for Magento CE 1.9, it has a REST/SOAP api. The best step forward is to contact your ERP vendor and ask them if they can provide an integration for magento (hopefully free of charge). I'm sure you're not the first one to ask them this question.